# How to force hibernate not to load subentities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have A and B entities where A can have more Bs

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
private Set<B> bs;

}
```

what I need is to say jpa somehow not to load set of Bs in special situations.

I tried it other way around, I defined fetch = FetchType.Lazy and then I say hibernate when i want to load B. Problem is however, that when i do a.getBs(), hibernate loads the bs even when i dont want this behaviour ( I wanted only check if B is loaded or not). It means I need to force hibernate with jpa not to load subentities later (a.getBs()) with lazy load mode OR to force not to load entities with eager load mode.

In jpa there is method Root.fetch(). I would need Root.unfetch()

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? You will get better help if people know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If I understand correct when you call a.getBs you dont want to load bs?

Comment: yes exactly.. when i call a.getBs i dont want to load bs.
@forgivenson I do a remapping of Entities to model and i want to remap only those, which has been loaded in the first query

Comment: does that make any sense? if you don't want the B dont call getter?

Comment: @Zeromus yes it does. Based on that (loaded or not loaded), I do other functionality

Comment: @simon77 even you have a working method bs never be loaded with that logic always null or empty check will return true, try to add another utility method something like boolean isBsLoaded() return this.bs != null && bs.size > 0 ... Anyway I didnt tested just storming

Comment: @HRgiger if I did it, hibernate would do query to db and load bs... easiest way is to use eager load and somehow tell hibernate not to load bs

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to move `a` out of the method that creates the transaction, and then call `a.getBs()`. If you have it lazy loaded, it won't be able to fetch it outside of the transaction.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    // this must be LAZY for this to work
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private Set<B> bs;

}

...

public void outsideTransaction() {
    A a = getA();

    // a.getBs() will return null if it was never called inside method getA()
    if(a.getBs() == null) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
}

public A getA() {
    // transaction starts in this method, however you are handling transactions
    A a = // query for record from table A;

    // do stuff that may or may not involve calling a.getBs()

    return a;
    // transaction ends
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate provide functionality for the check without fetching.

If you keep Lazy fetching
you can add this method in the parent entity

```
public boolean isBLoaded() {
    if (bs instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        if (((HibernateProxy)bs ).getHibernateLazyInitializer().isUninitialized()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The point is to not call the getter or you will fetch the association

Comment: is there a JPA API equivalent for this?

Comment: i don't know about that sorry, but if you don't care about exposing Hibernate specific API (you are not going to change jpa provider) it should work without issue

Comment: well, actually it can happen in future. That's why we work with JPA. But thanks anyway :)